# How to get the minimum and maximum value from a Json

Tags: json, d3.js

I want the minimum and maximum value(in the file called size) from a json file. How it is possible with d3js and javascript? What opportunities there are to iterate through the json file?

The example json:
[flare.json](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/flare.json)

Original d3js visual [circle packing](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html)

---

How to get the same with a complex json file like this: [json file](http://pastebin.com/kzisNJQ6)

There are metrics for the whole project, packages and classes(Klassen). 
How to get the minimum and maximum LinesofCode of the classes (Klassen)?

Comment: You can use d3.extent or d3.max and d3.min.  See [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_min) for the API documentation.  Also check out [Phoebe Bright's post on nesting](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand it, D3.js will not be helpful for such a task. In pure JS, your JSON files can be convert into plain objects and parse. I do not provide a generic solution because the structure and the data you want to compare really differ from one file to the other. But the idea will always be the same : traverse the tree structure of the JSON file from root to leafs looking for the data to compare with a recursive function (base on the structure of your first JSON file) :

```
function recursion(obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty("size")){
        // if the current object has the 'size' property
        // do what you want with 'size'
    } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        // if the current object has the 'children' property
        // recursively repeat for each children
        obj.children.forEach(function(child){
            result.recursion(child);
        });
    }
}

recursion(data); //data is the object created from the JSON file
```

flare.json (min and max values of **size** for all elements): http://jsfiddle.net/3LEeM/1/

the second JSON file (min and max values of **LinesofCode** for **Klassen** only): http://jsfiddle.net/RA6gb/